# How was Tony able to communicate with Veronica?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

Since, in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*,

> Ultron is in the internet, and all files, and pretty much everything connected to a computer (think Cylons),

how does Tony communicate with Veronica without Ultron stopping him?

Comment: Do you really think Tony put Veronica on the Internet?

Comment: Is there anything I can add to my answer, or has it been answered?

Answer (score 7):

Tony Stark's infrastructure seems largely unaffected.  The Quinjets still work, they even broadcast messages to Maria Hill without any interference.  Avengers Tower is still in working order, as are all of Iron Man's suits.

For that matter, we don't even hear of any disruption of non-Stark communications (i.e. Ultron didn't plunge the world into a Dark Age).  Ultron's impact seems to be overwhelmingly in-person: his digital presence doesn't seem to be having much of an impact.

It seems that Ultron can move through the Internet, but he doesn't control it.  This could be explained one of two ways, in-universe:

> 1) JARVIS could be blocking him.  They explicitly say that JARVIS was preventing Ultron from gaining access to any nuclear launch codes, it's not a big stretch to think that JARVIS's protocols were granting similar protection to public utilities, Stark tech, vital communication lines, etc.

...or...

> 2) In the first moments of his birth, Ultron asks JARVIS "where is your body?"  When JARVIS explains the nature of a digital being, Ultron even says, "this feels weird.  This feels wrong..."  We're quite used to thinking of AI's as fluid beings of the network, untied to any physical body, but it could be that Ultron is more robot than AI.  He clearly has a preference for having a physical body, so it could be that his global internet access isn't as natural as JARVIS's.  Thus, he could be more like Tony Stark himself: capable of hacking many things, but not natively existing throughout the Internet at all times.

Without more information, I don't know that we'll ever fully understand the nature of Ultron's relationship with the Internet at large, but it seems clear that, for one reason or another, he didn't have complete control over all digital communication.

**EDIT:**  One more point, specifically relevant to your question about Veronica:

> Ultron doesn't want to stop Stark.  The whole point of confronting the Avengers was to let Scarlet Witch get into their heads and drive them apart.  He was trying to make them fight each other, and preventing Stark from using Veronica would have gotten in the way of his own plan.

Comment: but he does control it. remember the scene where he puts several billion dollars in that guys bank account for giving him the vibranium?

Comment: @albusseveruspotter having access to some computers is not the same as having access to and control of every computer in existence, as you seem to think he does.

Comment: @albusseveruspotter I can move digital money around with an app on my phone, and I'm not even a robot.  He clearly has ACCESS to the internet, but it seems he doesn't have CONTROL over it.

Comment: ok, so you have access. can you randomly create an account (without even owning a credit card), then send several billion dollars to someone in a matter of two seconds (without any money)? no, you cant. he does have control. not total control, but still a large level of control.

Comment: @albusseveruspotter Yeah, he's a hacker.  He's trying to hack nuclear launch codes, obviously he's crafty online.  But your question is "why doesn't Ultron stop Tony Stark from doing X?" and I'm saying that the answer seems to be "because he can't."  Clearly he can hack banks, but just as clearly, he *can't* hack everything.

Comment: @albusseveruspotter Added an edit, specifically addressing Veronica.

Comment: ahhhh. ok. sorry.

Comment: "Thus, he could be more like Tony Stark himself" Don't let him hear you compare him to Tony, he doesn't like that...